# define *struct in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to convert regexitem *regex to ctype variable, any ideas?

C function expects func(regexitem *regex)

```
    char *regex1Groups[] = { "a","b","x","s" ,NULL};
    char *regex2Groups[] = { "l" ,NULL};

    regexitem regex[] = {
            {"bla", regex1Groups,4 },
            {"bla2",regex2Groups,1 }
    };
```

First i defined

```
class regexitem(Structure): 
        _fields = ("regex",c_char_p), ("groups",c_char_p*size), ("groupsize",c_int)
```

and ran into first problem, declaring array of regexitem because size of groups is not known in advance.

Comment: Disregarding anything else, you've got a syntax error in your class definition. That should be `_fields_`, not `_fields`.

Comment: stupid typo, original source has it right, but tnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs can only contain variable-length arrays at their ends, and on top of that when you assign an array variable to something you aren't copying it, you're assigning the memory location of the first element of the array. So I'm betting that your `regexitem` struct contains a pointer to the array of `char` pointers rather than containing the array of `char` pointers itself. If that's the case, this might work:

```
class regexItem(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("regex", c_char_p),
                ("groups", POINTER(c_char_p)),
                ("groupsize", c_int),
                ]
```

(You can keep the assignment to `_fields_` as a tuple of tuples rather than a list of tuples if you want to.)

Oh, for your regex groups, it'd be something like this:

```
regex1Groups = (c_char_p * 5)("a", "b", "x", "s", None)
regex2Groups = (c_char_p * 2)("l", None)
```

And then your array of `regexitem`s would be like so:

```
regex = (regexItem * 2)(("bla", regex1Groups, 4),
                        ("bla2", regex2Groups, 1))
```

Look through the `ctypes` documentation if you want to know more.

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html